# The ASP.NET MVC Routing Querystring vs Embedded Value Bewilderment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

This has probably been asked already - if so sorry! I couldn't find it.
I am unsure as to how asp is able to decide when to use a query string and "normal looking paths" (Embedded values)
Take this for example:

```
routes.MapRoute(

    "SomePage",
    "Net/Fix/{value}",
    new { controller = "Net", action = "Index" }
    );

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

I don't know how to explain - I will try.. If I am wrong please explain it

Question 1.
Is the first argument in mapRoute so that we can specify which routing we want to take place when using hyperlinks?

Question 2.
What does the second argument do? 
It appears as if the second argument gives you the option of specifying how the routing should occur as below: "Net/Fix/hello" or by specifying placeholders in the form of {controller}/{action}/{somevar}

Question 3: 
I assume if nothing is used in question 2 scenario - this specifies default routing that should take place?

Question 4: 
How does ASP.NET infer whether to use a query string or an embedded value..

Because for example when I decide to call my page

```
http:/localhost:portno/Net/Fix/hello
```

It dutifully prints hello.. but when I do *this*

```
http:/localhost:portno/Net/Index/hello
```

It doesn't work.. unless I do

```
http:/localhost:portno/Net/Index?value=hello..
```

Question is... *why?!!!*

I hope questions were clear.. I will reply to answers (if any later).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument is a route name. Each route should have a unique name, and they can be used for creating links, to assure a link is based on a certain route. It's not important in your case of *matching* a route.

The second argument is a matching pattern. Literal values are shown in clear, and parameterized values inside curly braces. `{}`. The parameterized values are not just for specifying the location of a parameter, but also the *name* of it.

I'm not sure offhand why you would define a route without any matching pattern. Does such an overload of `MapRoute()` exist?

The reason you get the behavior you do with this url: `http:/localhost:portno/Net/Index?value=hello` It matches the *second* (the default) route, not the first.

However, look at the second route pattern:

```
"{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

The controller is the first parameter, action is the second. So with your URL, that request is routed to the `Net` controller, `Index` action. the same as your first example.

Because the query string contains a `value` parameter, that still gets passed to the action method. And it just so happens your action method has a `string` parameter named `value`, so it works.

Comment: Yeah the overload works, sorry but you didn't really explain the query string question.
I know "Net/Index" matches the second one - I just don't *know* why it matches with a query string: "Net/Index?value=hello" as opposed to "Net/Index/hello" which works for the first map route. There is nothing in both routes that distinguishes between a query string and  using embedded values. Please explain.
Thanks..

Comment: Another question: I noticed the route name is used in RouteLinks - I assumed that was the purpose of giving routing a name.. otherwise I don't see how asp knows which one to use as we never specify the routing name in the url.. 
I get what you mean by {} values specifying the location.. however the *name*? That's a bit confusing..